# pytest using modules with logger

Tags: logging, pytest

Consider the following structure:

```
/dir
  py_pack_a
    __init__.py
    file_a.py

  py_pack_b
    __init__.py
    file_b.py

conftest.py
pytest.ini
test_file.py
```

The conftest.py has the following implementation to write a log for every test

```
@pytest.hookimpl
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    logging_plugin = item.config.pluginmanager.get_plugin("logging-plugin")
    timestamp = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    logging_plugin.set_log_path(os.path.join('logs', f'{item.name}_{timestamp}.log'))
```

The pytest.ini looks like:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -rA
log_cli = true
```

Everthing works only if the logger is defined in py_pack_a/file_a.py with something like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

If also a logger is defined in the same way in test_file.py the generated files are empty.
Could someone explain what the problem is?

I need a way to log from file_a.py, file_b.py, and test_file.py, and all logs are combined and written into one file per test.
Is this possible? If yes, how?

Tests are started with

```
pytest test_file.py
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not forgett to add the log level!

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Now everything workes